# Applet Based Jasper Report!

Tags: java, applet, jasper-reports

The thing I am doing is displaying Jasper Report in an JApplet in web browser. Eeverything is working fine except two.

1. The detail section of my report is not showing up in the applet. I'm sure that there is no issue with the report filling as the values of query fields put in other sections like page header are showing up. Only the detail section is missing. Can anyone give some idae about the cause?
2. The SAVE button of the JR Viewer in the applet is not working. Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

About the first question, the Detail section (unlike other sections) is related to the Data Query of the entire report. So you should make sure the report query is returning at least one record for the Detail section to appear.

Suggestion, you can export your report to PDF and open it using the browser, I believe this would be better than loading an Applet each time.